# Visual Studio App Center not displaying crash logs

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

am using visual studio  and i have integrated app center for visual studio (for iOS)as like in their documentation.

I can able to see the analytics report in appcenter portal, even i can see log flow for each session. but i couldn't see  crash reprots in crashlytics portal. tried with all steps, like uploading dSYM file, nothing works out. any body faced same issues?

Comment: use the chat function on each page to talk to a member of the engineering team

Comment: Unhandled exceptions can be found under Diagnostics > Crashes Tab. If you are looking for Handled Exceptions then it would fall under Diagnostics > Errors Tab. If you are not seeing this tab, then you have to contact AppCenter via the Chat button and ask them to enable this feature for your account. Because, this feature is yet in Preview Mode and we have to explicitly request them to enable. Also make sure you are initializing it like AppCenter.Start("xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));  https://github.com/Microsoft/AppCenter-SDK-DotNet/issues/140

Answer (score 4):

On iOS, it's not possible to use more than one third-party crash reporting tool at a time. Your issue most likely is that you added both the App Center and the Crashlytics SDK but only one of them is able to actually catch and report the crashes. This is a result of how crash reporting works on iOS but note that it only applies to "real" crashes, not handled errors.

You have to pick one of the SDKs to do the crash reporting for you and remove/disable the functionality in the other.